# Will I meet trouble if I rename a package with uppercase letter?

Tags: android

I hope to rename a package name under the folder \src , I see the following warning.

By convention, the package names usually start with a lowercase letter

Will I meet trouble if I rename a package with uppercase letter?

[image]

Comment: Men will shun you and women will just shake their heads.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill -- you do know how to paint a picture.. !!!

Comment: And we want to know why.

Comment: No, because you want to use mixed case in a package name. *Why* do you want to?

Comment: Thanks. What does it mean "Men will shun you and women will just shake their heads" because my question" ? I can't understand completely it becasue English is not my natrue language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because it's an acronym doesn't mean you should capitalize it in your package name. Class naming convention recommends making only the first letter in acronym-ish name portions upper-case, although for historical reasons there are classes that don't follow that convention.

The bottom line is that as long as it's a legal name, you're fine from the Java side of things.

Mixed-case directories sometimes cause issues across OSes, particularly combined with version control. For practical reasons alone it might be worth following convention.

Comment: Thanks! Is it Ok to use  uppercase letter in class name such as BLLHandleLogs.jave ?

Comment: @user828896 Same answer, same reasons not to--I already addressed this in my answer.